# LiveData not updating UI when RecyclerView Item Clicked

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I've got a grocery list I'm loading onto my sectioned recyclerview, checked and unchecked items in a HashMap.

Using MVVM, Room database, and am in the middle of a transition to Kotlin with Coroutine

Right now when I click an item it's getting updated via my ViewModel class and updating the database in the background. But the UI is not getting updated unless I kill and reopen the application. Then all of the items that were clicked before now change to either checked or unchecked.

**Parent adapter class**

```
class GrocerySectionAdapter(
    private val activity: Context,
    private var itemList: HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>,
    private val viewModel: GroceryListViewModel,
    private val lifeCycle: LifecycleOwner
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GrocerySectionAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    inner class MyViewHolder(val viewDataBinding: ParentRecyclerViewBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewDataBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): GrocerySectionAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val binding =
            ParentRecyclerViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if (position == 1)
            holder.viewDataBinding.section.text = "Remove checked items"
        else holder.viewDataBinding.section.visibility = View.GONE

        holder.viewDataBinding.childRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter =
                itemList[position]?.let { GroceryListAdapter(activity, it, viewModel, lifeCycle) }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return itemList.size
    }

    fun setGroceries(groceries: HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>) {
        this.itemList = groceries
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Child adapter class**

```
    class GroceryListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var groceries: List<GroceryItem>,
    private var viewModel: GroceryListViewModel,
    private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryListViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroceryListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val groceryItem = groceries[position]
        holder.bind(groceryItem)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroceryListViewHolder {
        val listItemBinding = ListItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )

        val holder = GroceryListViewHolder(listItemBinding, viewModel, lifecycleOwner)

        listItemBinding.lifecycleOwner = holder
        listItemBinding.itemClicked = viewModel

        holder.lifecycleCreate()

        return holder
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return groceries[position].uid.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return groceries.size
    }

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: GroceryListViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        holder.attachToWindow()
    }
}


override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: GroceryListViewHolder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    holder.attachToWindow()
}
```

**View Model Class**

```
class GroceryListViewModel(application: Application, private val groceryListRepo: GroceryListRepo) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    val listedGroceries = groceryListRepo.listedGroceries as MutableLiveData<HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>>

    fun updateGrocery(groceryItem: GroceryItem?) {

        uiScope.launch {

            groceryListRepo.updateGrocery(groceryItem)
        }
    }

    fun updateGroceries(groceryItems: List<GroceryItem?>?) {

        uiScope.launch {

            groceryListRepo.updateGroceries(groceryItems)
        }
    }

    fun updateClickedGrocery(groceryItem: GroceryItem) {

        groceryItem.isChecked = !groceryItem.isChecked

        updateGrocery(groceryItem)
    }

}
```

**Repository Class**

```
    public class GroceryListRepo {

    private final LiveData<List<GroceryItem>> groceryItems;

    private final MutableLiveData<HashMap<Integer, List<GroceryItem>>> listedGroceries = new MutableLiveData<>();
    
    GroceryItemDao groceryItemDao;
    private final Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public GroceryListRepo(GroceryItemDao groceryItemDao) {

        this.groceryItemDao = groceryItemDao;
        groceryItems = groceryItemDao.getAllListedGroceries();
    }

    public LiveData<HashMap<Integer, List<GroceryItem>>> getListedGroceries() {

        mExecutor.execute(() -> {
            List<GroceryItem> checkedGroceries = groceryItemDao.getAllListedCheckedGroceries();
            List<GroceryItem> unCheckedGroceries = groceryItemDao.getAllListedUncheckedGroceries();

            HashMap<Integer, List<GroceryItem>> mapListedGroceries = new HashMap<>();

            if (!checkedGroceries.isEmpty()) {

                mapListedGroceries.put(CHECKED_GROCERIES, checkedGroceries);
            }
            if (!unCheckedGroceries.isEmpty()) {

                mapListedGroceries.put(UNCHECKED_GROCERIES, unCheckedGroceries);
            }

            listedGroceries.postValue(mapListedGroceries);
        });

        return listedGroceries;
    }

    public LiveData<List<GroceryItem>> getAllGroceries() {
        return groceryItemDao.getAllGroceries();
    }

    public void updateGrocery(GroceryItem groceryItem) {

        groceryItemDao.updateGrocery(groceryItem);
    }

    public void updateGroceries(List<GroceryItem> groceryItems) {

        groceryItemDao.updateGroceries(new GroceryItem[groceryItems.size()]);
    }
}
```

**Activity class**

```
    GroceryItemDao dao = AppDatabase.getAppDataBase(this).groceryItemDao();
    GroceryListRepo repo = new GroceryListRepo(dao);

    GroceryListFactoryViewModel factory = new GroceryListFactoryViewModel(repo, getApplication());
    groceryListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(GroceryListViewModel.class);

    GrocerySectionAdapter adapter = new GrocerySectionAdapter(GroceryListActivity.this,
            listedGroceries,
            groceryListViewModel,
            this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    groceryListViewModel.getListedGroceries().observe(this,
            groceryItems -> {

                listedGroceries = groceryItems;

                if (groceryItems.isEmpty()) {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    adapter.setGroceries(groceryItems);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please simplify the code before posting here, just post pieces of code that you have problems within, not everything related. It's too long and I have to read everything to understand

Comment: I've removed some extra code, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine. Except for one thing I suppose might be the issue is that `listedGroceries` in View Model class is `LiveData` rather than `MutableLiveData`. Try to use `MutableLiveData` see if the problem still happens.

Comment: Hey there I updated my code on the post to apply MutableLiveData to listedGroceries in ViewModel. Same issue where database is updated but no UI changes so far.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that `get()` is working 100% as expected for this scenario. Would you like to try to replace this  `val listedGroceries: MutableLiveData<HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>>
    get() = groceryListRepo.listedGroceries as MutableLiveData<HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>>`  to `val listedGroceries = groceryListRepo.listedGroceries as MutableLiveData<HashMap<Int, List<GroceryItem>>>`

Comment: I've updated the code and unfortunately still having the same issue :(